# How to get the java program completion status from unix shell script?

Tags: java, shell, unix

For example we are executing the below statement and we want to process further based on the status of java execution.

```
java -classpath  $CLASSPATH com.heb.endeca.batch.BatchManager "param1" "param2" "param3"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your Java code exits with [`System.exit(status)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29), you can get the status in Bash like this:

**Java:**

```
public class E {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.exit(42);
    }
}
```

**Bash:**

```
$ java E
$ echo $?
42
```

`$?` is the exit status of the last finished process.

Comment: Is there any other way to capture the status since in java System.exit() is not normal way to exit.

Comment: you can catch status using echo $?, even if java program does not exits with System.exit(), by default it returns 0 (means Success) status to Operating System on normal exit of program.

Answer (score 2):

java program should end with Sytem.exit(status). This number is returned as any other command in the operative system.

Answer (score 0):

As other's have stated, you need to use the `System.exit()` to get the desired output. The reason behind this is that `System.exit()` directly teminates the programs and exits returning the value as defined.

If you were wondering why we couldn't return anything from the `main` method, the answer is - in java `main` method never returns anything, if you analyze the golden required statement

```
public static void main()
```

you would see, in java main has a return type as `void`.

So, if you are checking for the return status of a java program from the calling program (Shell in this case), you are trying to read actually the exit status of `jvm` and not of your java program which would in normal condition be always zero (0) even tough if you program crashed due to any exception. You would get a non-zero exit status only if the jvm crashes due to unexpected reasons like `OutOfMemory` or something similarly critical.

Hope this helps in your understanding of catching exit status of the java program.